# Adding ! after click in event trigger doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events

```
$("div").bind("click", function() {
    $("body").append("<p>click event</p>");
}).bind("click.plugin", function() {
    $("body").append("<p>click.plugin event</p>");
})

$("button").click(function() {
    $("div").trigger("click!");  
});
```

In book said that `!` is to match all `click` methods which don't include in namespace. That means `click` the button only execute `click` event！

But this trigger doesn't work.

Comment: instead of   $("div").trigger("click!");  
it should be   $("div").trigger("click");

Comment: If I do this, ad the same time click.plugin event will be execute! I only want to execute click event!

Comment: In which book did you find something about `click!`?

Comment: Not only there's no such book, you should also close your `</p>` tags and learn the difference between `variable` and String `"string"`

Comment: I am in china, The book has a wrong argument, Do you have any good books about Jquery to suggestion?